# Tiling of $R^3$ with fixed number of neighbors $n$, limit on $n$?

Tags: graph-theory, tiling

$R^3$ can be tiled regularly with cubes, where each tile has six neighbors. If I do not care for the form of the tiles, but only for the number of neighbors, is there a limit on the number of neighbors if each tile shall have the same number of neighbors?

Since the form of the tiles is not important, this may well be eqivalent to the question about the degrees in an infinite non-planar graph where all degrees shall be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $n\times 1\times1$  blocks ("prismatic sticks"), forming horizontal layers of thickness $1$. The sticks in layers $2k-1\leq z\leq 2k$, $\>k\in{\mathbb Z}$,  are parallel to the $x$-axis, and the sticks in layers $2k\leq z\leq 2k+1$ are parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Not sure why the $2k$ gymnastics is needed, but I see that it is easy enough by arranging $n\times 1 \times 1$ block next to each other in each plane, while the even numbered planes have them parallel to the x-axis and the odd numbered ones have them parallel to the y-axis. Naturally each block then has 4 neighbours in its own plane plus $2n$ neighbours in the neighbouring planes. And $n$ can be arbitrarily large. I should not have said I don't care for the form of the tiles :-) I was thinking about something more isotropic.